# Error after updating dotnet-host Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04, .net-core

after the last update from .NET Core ppa, dotnet-host update, I can't anymore run the dotnet cli, I get just this error in terminal (running for eg dotnet --version command):

```
    Failed to resolve library symbol hostfxr_load, error: /usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/1.0.1/libhostfxr.so: undefined symbol: hostfxr_load
Failed to resolve library symbol hostfxr_unload, error: /usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/1.0.1/libhostfxr.so: undefined symbol: hostfxr_unload
This executable relies on newer functionality (exports) provided by 'libhostfxr.so'
  - Updating 'libhostfxr.so' to version '1.0.2-beta-000583-00' might help resolve this problem.
```

I already tried to clean everything about the .NET Core and reinstall again 
but nothing happens, anyone has idea about?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem [and found this link](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/227).  Short story is that I ran this to install dotnet-hostfxr version 1.0.2 and it resolved the dependency problem:

`sudo apt-get install dotnet-hostfxr-1.0.2`

Comment: Your link appears to be this very same page.

Comment: @AndrewArnott - Woops, fixed the link